# missing french accented characters in node url request

Tags: node.js, encoding, request

I'm getting in trouble with processing request, url of which contains french accents.

```
var url="http://www.babla.ru/dû";

console.log(url); //../dû, here it's OK

var requestOptions  = { encoding: "utf8", method: "GET", uri: url};

request(requestOptions, function (err, resp, body) {
console.log(resp.request.uri.href); //../d, here û is missing!
  ...
 }
});
```

Comment: I don't think that a URL with non-ASCII characters is valid.

Comment: @RHertel nope, when I go to link through browser - all is ok, I get normal redirect

Comment: I cannot open your link. It redirects me to the main page http://www.babla.ru/ (without the dû) at the end. Webpages often redirect automatically to the main page or to a standard error page when a link cannot be opened. That's the behavior of a browser. But if you try to access the URL directly with a code, you'll get an error because the URL doesn't exist.

Comment: That's because browsers know how to encode it properly. You probably need to be setting the URL as `encodeURI('http://www.babla.ru/dû')`, which is `"http://www.babla.ru/d%C3%BB"`. Let me know.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thank you, encodeURI() works fine. Now I get trouble with getting the word with accent after last slash. I used resp.request.uri.href.lastIndexOf("/")) to get it, but now I get 'Accrire' instead of 'écrire', what should I do? I tried method decodeURI(), didn't help